# What is $/makefile.inc.system in makefile?

Tags: makefile

In the makefile, the following include statement.

```
include $/makefile.inc.system
```

What does `$` mean here?
When I changed `./` to `$/` in the other command lines, it is not working.
But in the include $/makefile.inc.system, it is working as ./
I couldn't find any explanation about it.

Answer (score 0):

`$/` in this case is just expanding a makefile variable like you would any other variable, e.g. `$(foo)`. Somewhere in the main makefile you should see the variable `/` defined with something like `/ = somedir`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.Is there any difference with ./makefile.inc.system? What is the difference between $/makefile.inc and ./makefile.inc? Why use $/makefile.inc form?

Comment: You'll need to look at the makefile to determine why it uses a variable instead of hard-coding the path, my guess is it's to allow `makefile.inc` to be dynamically included from somewhere else.

Comment: I couldn't find "/=" and `include $/makefile.ins` is working, but `cp -p ./test.c ..` is changed to `cp -p $/test.c ..` , then fail. It looks still confusing.